# MVC optional parameter for method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create an optional parameter for an ActionResult method.

I have the following:

```
    public ActionResult ViewReq (int id, string Req = null)
```

When I tried to do the following:

```
    http://localhost/RepMedia/Controller1/ViewReq?id=34343?Req="34233"
```

I tried the following but got an error:

> An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with 'id'. The id must be part of the base URI:

```
http://localhost/RepMedia/Controller1/ViewReq/34343?Req=34233
```

Answer (score 3):

```
http://localhost/RepMedia/Controller1/ViewReq?id=34343&Req=34233
```

Use a question sign before the first parameter - all others should be split by ampersand.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult ViewReq (int? id, string Req)

http://localhost/RepMedia/Controller1/ViewReq?id=34343&Req=34233
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need make a string parameter optional, as they are reference types whose values will be null anyway if they aren't passed in by MVC.  That URL would end up with a non-null "Id", but null "Req".